# intersection of vector and matrix by names

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have a character called sl

```
[1]   a     b     c
```

and a matrix called returns.ts.

```
     a     b     d
[1]  2     3     4
[4]  1     2     3
[7]  4     3     2
```

I would like to get the intersection of the names of the character and matrix with the data from the matrix, like so:

```
      a     b
 [1]  2     3
 [3]  1     2
 [5]  4     3
```

I have tried using the code

```
r.sl <- returns.ts[intersect(names(returns.ts), names(sl))]
```

however, the created object appears empty.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `colnames(returns.ts)` instead

Comment: Thank you for your advice, unfortunately the object still appears empty.

Comment: yours can also work, but you also need a comma after the bracket in your last expression

Comment: That returns a matrix  with all the col names but no observations and no intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to pass the names of list element to the `j` of the matrix to returns required columns:

```
returns.ts[, names(sl)]
```

Check that sl is a list, not a vector -- `class(sl)`.

Comment: well, it works for this example e.g. if names in `sl` is a subset of cols. otherwise you need to filter `sl`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, unfortunately i have a character not a vector as i first imagined it. i have updated the question. when i use "returns.ts[,names(sl)]" i get a list of all the dates of returns.ts.

Comment: this should do than: `returns.ts[, sl]`

Comment: worked perfectly, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
test <- matrix(1:12,ncol = 3)
colnames(test) <- c('a','b','d')
sl <- setNames(c(10,20,40),c('a','b','c'))
test[,which(colnames(test) %in% names(sl))]
```

Comment: thank you for your help, when I run this code on my data I again get a time series list of all my date stamps from the returns.ts series.